# Percentage decrease based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

My dataframe looks like this:

```
question   timeSpent
a          5354
b          2344
c          2555
d          5200
e          3567
```

I want to add an extra column, `Score`, which contains values between `0` and `1`. The greater the `timeSpent` (expressed in seconds) is, the closer to 0 the `Score`. If the time spent is smaller, then the `Score` approaches 1.

Suppose the value is `1` if `timeSpent` is smaller or equal than `2500`. Then it drops by `20%` with every `100` seconds that have passed. If it hits or is greater than `5500`, it stays at `0`.

So for `2600`, the score would be `0.8`, for `2700` the score would be `0.64` etc.

I wrote if-else statements for every interval, but I think there must be a quicker way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to calculate the score and apply it to every `timeSpent`

```
def get_score(num):
    if num <= 2500: return 1
    if num >= 5500: return 0
    x = 1
    for _ in range((num - 2500) // 100):
        x *= 0.8
    return x

df = pd.DataFrame({'question': [a, b, c, d, e], 'timeSpent': [5354, 2344, 2555, 5200, 3567]})
df['Score'] = df.timeSpent.apply(lambda x: get_score(x))
```

Output:

```
  question  timeSpent     Score
0        a       5354  0.001934
1        b       2344  1.000000
2        c       2555  1.000000
3        d       5200  0.002418
4        e       3567  0.107374
```